# Arithmetic quiz with class database and score analysis

Tags: python, csv, statistics, quiz

I have done this quiz project and I have tried as hard as I could when I was writing to make it user friendly to read. Could you help me on improving and making it more user friendly please.

```
import random
import operator
import csv

OPERATIONS = [
(operator.add, "+"),
(operator.mul, "*"),
(operator.sub, "-")
]

NB_QUESTIONS = 10

def get_int_input(prompt=''):
    while True:
      try:
        return int(input(prompt))
      except ValueError:
    print("Not a valid input (integer is expected)")

def get_bool_input(prompt=''):
while True:
    val = input(prompt).lower()
    if val == 'yes':
        return True
    elif val == 'no':
        return False
    else:
        print("Not a valid input (yes/no is expected)")

if __name__ == '__main__':
name = input("What is your name?").title()
print(name, ", Welcome to the OCR Controlled Assessment Maths Test")

score = 0
for _ in range(NB_QUESTIONS):
    num1 = random.randint(1,11)
    num2 = random.randint(1,11)
    op, symbol = random.choice(OPERATIONS)
    print("What is", num1, symbol, num2)
    if get_int_input() == op(num1, num2):
        print("Correct")
        score += 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect")

print("Well done", name, "you scored", score, "/", NB_QUESTIONS)

print("Are you in class 7, 8 or 9")
student_class = int(input())

if student_class>9:
    print("This is not a class")
    student_class = int(input())
if student_class<7:
    print("This is not a class")
    student_class = int(input())

if student_class == 7:
    print('Enter your score for test 2')
    test2 = int(input())
    print('Enter your score for test 3')
    test3 = int(input())
    with open('class7.csv', 'a', newline='') as fp:
            a = csv.writer(fp,delimiter=',')
            data=[[name,score,test2,test3]]
            a.writerows(data)
    print("Your score has been saved")
    f = open('class7.csv')    
    csv_f = csv.reader(f)
    newlist = []
    for row in csv_f:
            row[1] = int(row[1])
            row[2] = int(row[2])
            row[3] = int(row[3])
            minimum = min(row[1:4])
            row.append(minimum)
            maximum = max(row[1:4])
            row.append(maximum)
            average = round(sum(row[1:4])/3) 
            row.append(average)
            newlist.append(row[0:7])
    alphabetical = [[x[0], x[5]] for x in newlist]
    for entry in sorted(alphabetical):
            print(entry)

    Highscore = [[x[5], x[0]]for x in newlist]
    print('Highest scores')
    for entry in sorted(Highscore, reverse = True) :
            print(entry)

    averagescore = [[x[6], x[0]] for x in newlist]
    print('Average scores')
    for entry in sorted(averagescore, reverse = True) :
            print(entry)


if student_class == 8:
    print('Enter your score for test 2')
    test2 = int(input())
    print('Enter your score for test 3')
    test3 = int(input())
    with open('class8.csv','a',newline='') as fp:
            a = csv.writer(fp,delimiter=',')
            data=[[name,score,test2,test3]]
            a.writerows(data)
    print("Your score has been saved")
    f = open('class8.csv')    
    csv_f = csv.reader(f)
    newlist = []
    for row in csv_f:
            row[1] = int(row[1])
            row[2] = int(row[2])
            row[3] = int(row[3])
            minimum = min(row[1:4])
            row.append(minimum)
            maximum = max(row[1:4])
            row.append(maximum)
            average = round(sum(row[1:4])/3) 
            row.append(average)
            newlist.append(row[0:7])
    alphabetical = [[x[0], x[5]] for x in newlist]
    for entry in sorted(alphabetical):
            print(entry)

    Highscore = [[x[5], x[0]]for x in newlist]
    print('Highest scores')
    for entry in sorted(Highscore, reverse = True) :
            print(entry)

    averagescore = [[x[6], x[0]] for x in newlist]
    print('Average scores')
    for entry in sorted(averagescore, reverse = True) :
            print(entry)

if student_class == 9:
    print('Enter your score for test 2')
    test2 = int(input())
    print('Enter your score for test 3')
    test3 = int(input())               
    with open('class9.csv','a',newline='') as fp:
            a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
            data=[[name,score,test2,test3]]
            a.writerows(data)
    print("Your score has been saved")
    f = open('class9.csv')    
    csv_f = csv.reader(f)
    newlist = []
    for row in csv_f:
            row[1] = int(row[1])
            row[2] = int(row[2])
            row[3] = int(row[3])
            minimum = min(row[1:4])
            row.append(minimum)
            maximum = max(row[1:4])
            row.append(maximum)
            average = round(sum(row[1:4])/3) 
            row.append(average)
            newlist.append(row[0:7])
    alphabetical = [[x[0], x[5]] for x in newlist]
    for entry in sorted(alphabetical):
            print(entry)

    Highscore = [[x[5], x[0]]for x in newlist]
    print('Highest scores')
    for entry in sorted(Highscore, reverse = True) :
            print(entry)

    averagescore = [[x[6], x[0]] for x in newlist]
    print('Average scores')
    for entry in sorted(averagescore, reverse = True) :
            print(entry)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A major step towards better readability of your code would be to introduce docstrings (for an "official" guideline see [PEP257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)) or at least some comments where you explain your intension.

Your check where the user inputs his class will fail if the second input of the user is still invalid.

```
print("Are you in class 7, 8 or 9")
student_class = int(input())

if student_class>9:
    print("This is not a class")
    student_class = int(input())
if student_class<7:
    print("This is not a class")
    student_class = int(input())
```

As none of the three following if-clauses applies to say `10`, the program will exit silently without tellig the user something went wrong.

Looking further, there seems to be a whole lot of redundant code in your class-specific checks (`if student_class == 7:` and so on). It is good practice to put such code into a function and pass e.g. the filename as argument. I will leave that as an exercise to you, but I'm willing to help if you face serious troubles doing that.

The variable `Highscore` should be all lowercase as well. You may have a look at [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for Python's naming recommendations. To easily check for such common mistakes, I personally would recommend to have a look at [Pylint](https://www.pylint.org/) which will do such basic checks for you automatically. But it is not perfect and may lead to confusion if you are a real beginner.

Please consider replacing the calls to open the csv-files (`f = open('classX.csv')`) with `with`-statements too. The [example section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples) in the `csv`-module shows you exactly how to do it.